# How to add a button to the left of search field?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to add a button to the search field so it would look something like this?

[image]

Here's my code:

```html
<div id="search">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Search U.K. house price data</h1>
    <form class="has-success has-feedback has-feedback-left">
      <label class="control-label sr-only" for="inputSearch">Search U.K. house price data</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="inputSearch" placeholder="Enter a postcode, street or address">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></span>
      <button class="btn" type="submit">SEARCH</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Here' what I got using this code:**

[image]

```
.btn {
position:absolute;
top: 20px;
right: 100px;
```

}

Comment: Share the CSS that you've tried

Comment: .btn {
 position:absolute;
 top: 20px;
 right: 100px;
}

Comment: Change right to left.

Comment: Nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set height of form to the same `height` of search bar and add `position:relative`

Also then you will need to change your button top value.

Form is a parent element of your button and absolute elements watch for closest parent with `position:relative` and positions itself absolute inside container of this parent.

Comment: I can fix your code if you post full css of the form, not just button part. I'll just create jsfiddle and point out changes for you. :)

Comment: How I've done this: #search form {
 height: 100px;
}
#search form input {
 height: 60px;
 position: relative;
 border-radius: 30px;
 max-width: 970px;
}

Comment: #search {
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 background-size: cover;

Comment: But I didn't have any css of the form before.

Comment: #search form { height: 100px; }, as this is parent of your button add here position: relative

Comment: #search form {
 height: 100px;
 position: relative;
}
#search form input {
 height: 60px;
 border-radius: 30px;
 max-width: 970px;
}

#search {
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 background-size: cover;
}

That way?

Comment: yup, this should help

Answer (score 0):

it can be like that
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shady_youssery/0kwax0vp/1/)

css

```
.btn {
position:absolute;
top: 5px;
right: 10px;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 1px;
border-radius: 18px;}
.form-control-feedback{
left:0;
}
#inputSearch{
  padding-left: 30px;
  border-radius: 18px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="search">
 <div class="container">
 <h1>Search U.K. house price data</h1>
 <form class="has-success has-feedback has-feedback-left">
   <label class="control-label sr-only" for="inputSearch">Search U.K. house price data</label>
   <input class="form-control" type="text" id="inputSearch" placeholder="Enter a postcode, street or address">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></span>
   <button class="btn" type="submit">SEARCH</button>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the promblem with it?

Comment: it may be conflict style with another. so I have updated jsfiddle by make position, top and right !important https://jsfiddle.net/shady_youssery/0kwax0vp/3/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0kwax0vp/4/

!important has no influence. Unless somewhere else in your css there is some other styles that have higher hierarchy. :)